# Character getting faster everytime I reset my game from gameover screen in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, game-physics

My game starts with a start frame. click a button to the game. if I hit an object I go to game over screen. Everytime I hit the start over button on the game over screen my characters controls get faster. I have set no variables for speed, simply just "mc_guy.x +=3" or .y , etc. If I had to say by how much faster I would want to say that the speed doubles.

```
   import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


//prevent game loop
stop();

// event listeners for movement
mc_Guy.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownGuy);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUpGuy);


// this array holds references to all the keys
var keys:Array = [];



//initiate default values
fuelGauge.height = 100;




//Gravity
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Gravity)

var GyAmt:Number = 5;


function Gravity(e:Event){
mc_Guy.y += GyAmt;  

if (gameFloor.hitTestObject(mc_Guy)){
    mc_Guy.y = gameFloor.y;}
else if (gameFloor2.hitTestObject(mc_Guy)){
    mc_Guy.y = gameFloor2.y;}
else if (gameFloor3.hitTestObject(mc_Guy)){
    mc_Guy.y = gameFloor3.y;}}



// the event listeners
function update(e:Event):void
{
    if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT])
    {
        mc_Guy.x += 3;
    }

    if (keys[Keyboard.LEFT])
    {
        mc_Guy.x -= 3;
    }
    if (keys[Keyboard.SPACE]){
        mc_Guy.y -= 10;
                    //drain fuel
                    fuelGauge.height -= 1;
                    gaugePercent.text = String(fuelGauge.height)
                    if (fuelGauge.height == 0){
                        nextFrame();}}
}

function onKeyDownGuy(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}

function onKeyUpGuy(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;

}






//Array storing each wall
var MC_wall:Array = new Array(mc_Wall,mc_Wall2,mc_Wall5,
mc_Wall6,mc_Wall7,mc_Wall8,mc_Wall9,mc_Wall10,mc_Wall11,mc_Wall12, mc_Wall13)




//Collision Detection
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
function loop(e:Event){
        var i:Number = 0;
    do {
        if (MC_wall[i].hitTestObject(mc_Guy)){
            nextFrame();}
    i++;
    } while (i < MC_wall.length);


    /* for (var i:Number = 0; i < MC_wall.length; i++){
        if (MC_wall[i].hitTestObject(mc_Guy)){
            nextFrame();}
            }*/

     if(mc_Guy.hitTestPoint(mc_WallRun.x, mc_WallRun.y, false)){
            nextFrame();}
     else if(mc_Guy.hitTestObject(fuelPowerup)){
            removeChild(fuelPowerup);
            fuelGauge.height = 100;
            gaugePercent.text = String(fuelGauge.height)}
     else if(mc_Guy.hitTestObject(doorKey)){
        removeChild(doorKey)
                //open door 
            mc_Wall13.height -=20
            mc_Wall13.y -= 10
            }

}

//Object Movement
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
var spinSpeed:Number=6;
var axisMove:Number = 90;
var axisMovement:Number = 3;

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{ 
mc_WallRun.rotation+=spinSpeed; 
        //count the movement on axis and move 
        axisMove -= 3;
        mc_Wall9.x += axisMovement;
        gameFloor3.x += axisMovement * .9;
        if(axisMove <= 0){
        axisMove += 90
        axisMovement = axisMovement*-1
        }
}
```

Gameover frame:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

restartGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playAgain);
function playAgain(event:MouseEvent):void{
    prevFrame();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like when you restart your game

```
mc_Guy.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
```

is called again, without removing the previously added listener.

So update is now called two times on Event.ENTER_FRAME, and then once more per frame per game reset, causing the guy to move faster.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm still at a beginner level in programming and was unaware that I have to remove a listener. I was use to Visual Basic where a lot of could requires only a couple lines to work, as opposed to flash where it would take several lines to do the same thing.

Comment: @SorceressStabberThomas Glad I could be of some help :-)